# How to add new xml attributes to a set of xml documents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am normalizing into a pandas dataframe a bunch of xml documents from a directory. However, In order to do it correctly I think it is easier to assign to each xml document an id, for later concatenating all the documents in a single dataframe. Therefore, I tried to add a numerical id as follows:

```
for filepath in glob(os.path.join('../data/trainingFiles/', '*.xml')):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        xml_doc = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')
        for i, sentences in enumerate(xml_doc.find_all("sentence")):
            sentences['pandas_id'] = str(i)
            print(sentences)
```

However, the above code is adding to all the sentence attributes different numerical ids inside the same document. How can I assign a different id to each document (i.e. I would like to add the same id to all the elements inside a document)?.. is there any way of carrying a reference of which document I am adding the pandas id attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code, the `document_id` will change only with each file:

```
for document_id, filepath in enumerate(glob(os.path.join('../data/trainingFiles/', '*.xml'))):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        xml_doc = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'lxml')
        for sentences in xml_doc.find_all("sentence"):
            sentences['pandas_id'] = str(document_id)
            print(sentences)
```